# fetching records on vf with two object with lookup relation in them in salesforce

Tags: lookup, relationships

i have two object `Timeslot__c` and `Commercial_Slot__c`

i have a field name timeslot which is lookup in `commercial_slot__c` on `timeslot__c`

i am feching timeslot records on vf page and also want the commercial_slot objects

records with that.
so i try

```
select NumberofBroadcasts__c,
       Timeslot__r.ProgramName__c,
       Timeslot__r.ProgramGenre__c,
       Timeslot__r.AllowedCommercialTime__c,
       Timeslot__r.RemainingCommercialTime__c,
       Timeslot__r.ScheduledCommercialTime__c
from Commercial_Slot__c 
where Timeslot__c 
IN (select id from Timeslot__c)
```

so its working...but i want opposite to it. that from Timeslot__c object i want to featch commercial__c object records.
so please help me in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ProgramName__c, 
       ProgramGenre__c, 
       AllowedCommercialTime__c, 
       RemainingCommercialTime__c, 
       ScheduledCommercialTime__c,
       (SELECT Id, NumberofBroadcasts__c FROM Commercial_Slots__r) 
        FROM Timeslot__c
```

You may want this. Note: I am not aware of relationship name so just guessing

Comment: Just a side note - Wont this clause fetch all records? Having it or not having it will result the same I guess `FROM Timeslot__c Id IN (select id from Timeslot__c)`

Comment: thank u..its working propery the way i want..given code is correct.now i want to display the records on vf page. so i try this line of code.

Comment: thank u..its working propery the way i want..given code is correct.now i want to display the records on vf page. so i try this line of code.

Comment: thank u..its working propery the way i want..given code is correct.now i want to display the records on vf page. so i try this line of code <apex:column value="{!o.Commercial_Slots__c.NumberofBroadcasts__c}"/>

Comment: but it showing error..so how to access that records in vf page

Comment: use apex:repeat inside your pageblocktable use value="{!o.Commercial_Slots__c}" var="com" and inside that repeat use {!com.NumberofBroadcasts__c}